# Дана строка из латинских букв и цифр. Как из нее извлечь отдельно цифры и отдельно буквы? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дана строка из латинских букв и цифр. Как из нее извлечь отдельно цифры и отдельно буквы? (python)

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прогнать строку через цикл

- если содержится в (Aa-Zz):    в строку с буквами
- если содержится в (0-9):    в строку с цифрами

Comment: Какой вопрос такой ответ :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "123ba4"

numbers = []
symvoles = []

for char in s: 
    if char.isalpha():
       symvoles.append(char)
     else:
        numbers.append(char)
```

Вроде так но мог напутать с отступами, не работаю с `python`

Comment: @arthur Если помогло, поставьте галочку.